# Adding time stamp while loading data to Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am loading data into Hive table, original data does not have a time stamp, how to add time stamp while loading the data into hive table?

Comment: Do you want the time when the load took place? how are you loading the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you load data using a hive query, you can add a timestamp column in your table and populate it using the [`current_timestamp`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) udf.